# OpenWRT how to isolate a single client

Tags: openwrt

I have an IOT device that I want to isolate so that it can access the internet but not other devices on the LAN. I am not, however, looking to isolate all devices on the LAN. Its a pretty normal home setup with one AP. I do not use Luci. How do I achieve this?

I am aware it will not make it secure, it should be on a different network for that, however for now I just want to keep it from snooping around easily.